# State and prove the theorem allowing one to identify the eigenvalues of $f$?

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a question from one of my linear algebra past papers, and unfortunately the university has a policy of not sharing mark schemes.

After looking my lecture notes for the answer, this is the closest statement I can find:

> Let  $\lambda\in$F. Then $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $f$ if and only if $\chi_A(\lambda)= 0$,

What is the proof of this knowing that $\lambda$ is the  root of the characteristic polynomial $\chi_A(\lambda)= 0$?

Comment: Do you know how to form the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: @Arthur Something to do with calculating the det (A- $\lambda$ $I_n$) where $A$ is a matrix representing the basis of a linear map, and $n$ is the number of rows/columns in $A$.

Comment: When the determinant of the matrix $B=A-\lambda I$ is zero, that means a couple of things. Can you guess which consequence is relevant in our case?

Comment: @Arthur Ah, I see what you mean, say $A$ = a generic 2x2 matrix. then the determinant calculation will give you ($\lambda$ - a)($\lambda$ - b) = 0. Expanding this will give you a quadratic equation in terms of $\lambda$ (which I'm assuming is the characteristic polynomial), solving for $\lambda$ $is$ the process to find the eigenvalues, meaning the eigenvalues are the roots of the polynomial given from $A$. (yes/no/maybe?).

Comment: It's not wrong, but it's not what I was going for. What I meant was that if $\det(B) = 0$, then there is a vector $v$ such that $Bv = 0$. This gives
$$
Bv = 0\\
(A-\lambda I)v = 0\\
Av - \lambda Iv = 0\\
Av = \lambda I v\\
Av = \lambda v
$$which means that $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ and $\lambda$ is the corresponding eigenvalue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall the derivation of the characteristic polynomial as:
$$Ax = \lambda{}x \rightarrow (A-\lambda{}I)x = 0$$
If we want non-trivial solutions (that is.. our eigenvalues and respective eigenspaces), then what condition does the matrix $A - \lambda{}I$ need to fulfill? ($det[A - \lambda{}I] = 0$, why?)

Then if the characteristic polynomial, $P$ is the resultant $n$ root(why?) polynomial from $det[A - \lambda{}I] = 0$ and is in terms of $\lambda$ then if $$P(\lambda) = 0$$
By definition what does that say about $\lambda$?

**Note**: Determinant of a matrix is $=0$ if...? (the matrix is not invertible)
**Note**: $\lambda{}$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ since it fulfills $Ax = \lambda{}x$!

Comment: It is rather strange to ask questions to the reader in your answer, then immediately answer them without giving them the opportunity to think about it for themselves.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, an eigenvalue of a matrix $ A $ is $ \lambda $ such that there exists a vector $ v \neq 0$ satisfying $ Av = \lambda v $. We could also write this as $ (A - \lambda I) v = 0 $. Now, what does the existence of such a $ v $ tell you?